# Why is idle skipping over f = open('filename' , 'r')

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I'm writing a program in python and I am having issues getting idle to read my file out. If I use improper syntax it tells me, so it is being read by the compiler but not printing it for the user. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
#! python3.5.2

import sys

if input() == ('im bored'):
    print('What season is it?')
    if input() == ('summer'):
       f = open('callfilesummer.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: You aren't actually reading the file. Or printing it for that matter.

Comment: You're opening a file, that's all. It doesn't produce any output. What's more, Python is an _interpreted_ language, it doesn't need a compiler.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) is the Python documentation for input and output. Use one of the methods there to read your file, then print it out.

Comment: i tried f.read() and it did not recognize

Comment: @ForceBru That is incorrect; the default implementation, CPython, compiles Python code to bytecode, which is then run in a VM. (horribly off-topic, I know)

Comment: Add the line `print(f.read())` after opening the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only put file into variable 'f', so you need to read it or work it with someway to show it.

```
import sys

if input() == ('im bored'):
    print('What season is it?')
    if input() == ('summer'):
       f = open('callfilesummer.txt', 'r')
       print f.read()
       f.close()
```

You can find more way how to work with files on this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: okay, i didnt understand print could used in another way than print('this'). It is just telling it what needs to happen rather than a specific function. Thank you

Comment: You need to understand fact you have opended file in variable "f", so all operation go to that. Function read() does is read the file from begining to end in variable "f", which you also immediately print.

You could also store content of the file in other variable like `content = f.read()` and then `print content`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do anything. Maybe take a look at the Python documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

That's a start.

If you want to display the file, you can *very* easily iterate over a file in Python like this:

```
f = open('hurdurr', 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
```